# Website with bad rendering on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have implemented a website, originally optimized for Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera, with CSS3.

Now, I would like to get the same rendering with Internet Explorer. From what I have found on StackOverflow, the solution may be to add in `<head>` section :

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

But the rendering is not pretty (top and bottom menus are shifted and have not rounded corners) and I don't know how to fix it or at least improve it.

How can I achieve a better design under Internet Explorer browser, especially for IE 11 and recent versions?

Comment: If you use border-radius, it is not supported by IE8 (https://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Comment: -@Gerard thanks  ! Is this issue also appeared with recent versions of IE ?

Comment: From IE11 onwards it should work as expected.